# What is the Difference between running react native code on Web Browser and Expo GO?

Tags: react-native, web, browser, expo

I am running React Native Code on the Web browser and in Expo Go. In the web browser, it runs fine without any error but in Expo Go, it is not importing even a single module and showing module not found error again and again on almost all modules even after reinstalling them and also reinstalling node_modules.

Can anyone tell what's the difference between running react-native code on Expo Go and Web Browser?

Also what is this issue and how to solve it?